# Robotium Automation scripts failing when run on emulater 4.0 from VM

Tags: android, robotium

My android application is automated using Robotium which works without any issues on Emulator 4.0 on my local machine but when i run the automation scripts on VM it doesn't recognize a pop up and hence fails. Can u help ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-no-window` option when starting the emulator. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#startup-options

Comment: Thanks @Dave C but where can I find the -no-window option?

Comment: You use that option when you start the emulator from the command line. How do you start the emulator?

Comment: I do not start the emulator from command line, I start it from  Android Virtual Device Manager integrated with our Eclipse.